# using addslashes ’ character not storing to database Yii model->save()

Tags: php, yii

my string is 
    `$str = "Ranjit Hoskote’s The Complicit Observer provides an art-historical account of Sudhir Patwardhan’s";`

if i use `echo addslashes($str);` `model->save()`

the output is `Ranjit Hoskote`

`mysql_escape_string($str);` its storing into database only `Ranjit Hoskote`

how to store `’` character into database and retrieve from database

this is not a single quote `’` , it is a kind of special character

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: @jack the result is same as input

Comment: Yii will escape parameters automatically.

Comment: @Justinas its storing Ranjit Hoskote only